# Using Nordvpn premium on python script on a Heroku server

Tags: python, heroku, connection, vpn, integrate

The title describes it all. I want to access a site that blocked in the USA using a python script. I have hosted this on Heroku hence I can't use the script. I have a Nord premium and I was wondering if I can integrate that to Heroku host and us it , can anyone help me with the procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to take a look into the [nordvpn-connect](https://pypi.org/project/nordvpn-connect/) library. I have never tried this on Heroku, but it might work.

Comment: yh i tried that and for some mysteries reason bash command didn't seem to work :*)

Comment: You would have to give some more details in order for me to be able to help. What commands did you run and what was the error message?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, mate but I ended up using brightdata proxyies.Thanks anyway